# OneDrive failed to sync - "Sorry, OneDrive can’t add your folder right now", MachineIsNotAllowedToSync

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, ad, onedrive

I have two computers in discussion, one from work (joined in a company domain) and one personal. Trying to sync OneDrive for business on personal computer fails, with this message:

> Sorry, OneDrive can’t add your folder right now.

After hours of digging, debugging with Fiddle like here:
[OneDrive in fails to connect to Sharepoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264031/onedrive-in-fails-to-connect-to-sharepoint)

It turned out exactly the same problem

```
MachineIsNotAllowedToSync
```

Probably my computer is not "joined" in that active directory domain.

But I don't want AD at all, I just want my files when I work remotely.
This is complete crazy, since I can login to SharePoint from web browser just fine, access my folders, full access. Basically I create a TEST folder in SharePoint, upload files, download, do whatever I like.

But still OneDrive refuse to sync... seems not logical at all.

My one million question:

How can I provide required GUID or other way to solve this?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're attempting to bypass policies put into place by your workplace. I would suggest you speak with them about this policy, instead.

Comment: How come this is a POLICY BYPASS when from browser works perfect, but from OneDrive application not ?!?

Comment: Your company put limitations on the sync client but not on the web. They’re separate configs.